# Is there a comprehensive list of shortcuts/macros?

Tags: support

In comments, we can use shortcuts like [help], [su], [sf]. Is there a list of those? Can we expand them?

Answer (score 3):

There is a [comprehensive list of these 'magic links'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

<sub>I'm not reproducing the list here; that link is unlikely to break and we don't want to maintain that list in several places.</sub>